# Unit Inspection storage in SQL Server DB?

Tags: database-design

I am no DBA.  I do have quite a bit of experience in retrieving data out of a DB for reporting purposes, but the actual designing of one I have little to no experience with.  So I am hoping someone here can give me some guidance on the best way to achieve what I am trying to do:

One part of the database that I need to design is the storing of inspections of housing units and buildings.  A Building has one or more Units.  A Building also has Features (out side of the units like Stairways, walkway, a roof, etc). A Building with one Unit is a house.  An apartment building is a Building with multiple Units.  A Unit is made up of Spaces (rooms, halls, living room(s), kitchen(s), etc) and Spaces are made up of Features (Doors, windows, floors, ceilings, walls, appliances, outlets, etc.  Basically *everything* that would need to be inspected in a Unit).  Setting up the relationships between these objects seems fairly straight forward to me, but I need to also include some sort of Inspection object(s).  Both Buildings and Units will need to be inspected.  Buildings and Units (which there can be 10,000+ units in a given DB and 100s of Buildings) needs to be able to have multiple inspections stored (Buildings and Units will need to be inspected at least once a year) for historical purposes.  An Inspection will basically be made up of each Feature in a Building or a Unit (depending on if a Unit is being inspected or a Building).  Keep in mind that the Features in a unit and a Building can be unique to that Unit or Building.  What is the best way to implement the Inspection object(s) in the Building/Unit/Space/Feature relationship in a SQL Server DB?

Comment: There is inspection data for each feature? Does that data vary with the type. I'm guessing that there is some kind of checklist for each different kind of feature?

Comment: The only data for each Feature will be the same for each: a comment field, results field (Pass or Failed), and Date Resolved field.  Actual the checklist is for the Unit or Building themselves, and this is what I am trying to build with the Feature object, some sort of dynamtice Unit/Building checklist.

Thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would have a structure like:

```
property
id INT INCREMENT(1,1)
name VARCHAR(255)
...

inspectionObject
id INT INCREMENT(1,1)
name VARCHAR(255)
...

propertyInspection
id INT INCREMENT(1,1)
date DATETIME
inspector INT (FK: inspector table)
propertyID INT (FK: property table)
...

propertyInspectionResult
id INT INCREMENT(1,1)
inspectionID INT (FK: propertyInspection table)
inspectionObjectID INT (FK: inspectionObject table)
resultID INT (FK: result table)
```

Something like that should be a good structure to go to, it then allows you to record the details for each inspection once, but have the many objects for an inspection also recorded.  You can then undertake some pretty decent reporting based on the results and so on.

If you need any further information let me know.

Matt

Comment: Thanks Matt!  However, I was hoping to use the Feature object somehow, for this is how we will know what to inspect in each Unit and Building.  Does this make sense?

Thanks again for the help

Ben

Comment: That is easy, you create a table that would list the features, that link to property's and if the inspection is of the feature instead of the entire premises, then the propertyInspection table would link to the features table.

Comment: I think that might work!  Let me wrap my mind around it for awhile, but I think that will work!  Thank a million Matt!